# C++ getline() to fill vector

Tags: c++, csv, getline

I am back with a new problem. I need to fill a vector with csv data. Thought the best way was to implement a struct that has the same attributes as the csv data. Now I get getline() problems:

```
#include "fhir/persistence/hdf/HdfStorageAdapter.h" 
#include <macrologger.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream>

std::vector<row_struct> v;
std::string line;
std::ifstream dataInput(path.c_str());
char delimeter(',');
std::string timestampTemp, millisecondsSinceStartTemp, deviceTemp,
    typeTemp, valueTemp;
LOG_DEBUG("Reading data dump...");
int i = 0;
while (std::getline(dataInput, timestampTemp, delimeter)) {

    std::getline(dataInput, millisecondsSinceStartTemp, delimeter);
    std::getline(dataInput, deviceTemp, delimeter);
    std::getline(dataInput, typeTemp, delimeter);
    std::getline(dataInput, valueTemp);

    v[i].timestamp = atoi(timestampTemp.substr(1,
        timestampTemp.size() - 2).c_str());
    v[i].millisecondsSinceStart = atoi(millisecondsSinceStartTemp.substr(1,
        millisecondsSinceStartTemp.size() - 2).c_str());
    v[i].device = atoi(deviceTemp.substr(1, deviceTemp.size() - 2).c_str());
    v[i].value = atof(valueTemp.substr(1, valueTemp.size() - 2).c_str());
    v[i].type = *(typeTemp.substr(1, typeTemp.size() - 2).c_str());


    timestampTemp.clear();
    millisecondsSinceStartTemp.clear();
    deviceTemp.clear();
    typeTemp.clear();
    valueTemp.clear();

    i++;
}

return v;
```

Error code:

```
src/fhir/persistence/hdf/HdfStorageAdapter.cpp:129:9: error: no matching
  function for call to 'getline'
    std::getline(dataInput, valueTemp);
```

I get this for every call of 'getline()'.
Help is appreciated, as I did an extensive google search as well.

Comment: Can we see your include directives ?

Comment: @Pumkko yes its #include "fhir/persistence/hdf/HdfStorageAdapter.h"
#include <macrologger.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
at this moment i am trying to build it with sstream

Comment: `#include <string>` !

Comment: @KillzoneKid nope, unfortunately that does not change anything.

Comment: I am also getting this: 'In file included from src/fhir/persistence/hdf/HdfStorageAdapter.cpp:4:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/fstream:939:7: error: 
      exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base
      version
      ~basic_fstream()'

Comment: @Baesm that exception issue means that it likely has throw() added to it (meaning it will not throw in the destructor)

Comment: It would help if you told us which line is #129. The error you are getting is pretty self-explanatory: the `std::getline` function is being called with the wrong type of arguments.

Comment: @Ælex yes, but I got it to work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Add an answer explaining what you did to fix it, then. Questions left hanging with only "I fixed it" but not telling readers how are especially unuseful.